# Escape on Control key, Control on Capslock key, Capslock on Escape key

Tags: xorg, console, xkb

I'm looking for a method that works in both X and the console with console-setup (e.g. xkboptions, no X-exclusive methods like `xmodmap`). With XKBoptions, combining `ctrl:swapcaps` and `caps:swapescape` does not achieve the desired effect - it puts control on capslock (good) and capslock on both the control and escape keys.

For the curious / confused, the rationale is to optimize the keyboard layout by putting more frequently used functions on easy to reach keys.

Since I never use capslock anyways I would also settle for a solution that puts Control on CapsLock and Escape on Control and leaves the Escape key as is (leaving me with no CapsLock function).

Comment: A little off the mark, but maybe worth considering - with `kmscon` you can use any X  layout in the linux console - which is only one of many advantages it offers. http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/kmscon/

Comment: I was looking through `man` today for a different reason and tab completion brought several commands to my notice you might find interesting : `{load,dump,show}keys`, and `{g,s}etkeycodes` and several others. The `man` pages indicate that these are used to alter the kernel's interpretation of the keyboard drivers' scancodes. Some combination of those should get you what you want.

Answer (score 2):

## Adding a custom XKBOption

Debian uses the XKB system for both Xorg and console, so one method is to add a custom XKBOption. The relevant files on Debian are located under `/usr/share/X11/xkb`, files [provided](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/all/xkb-data/filelist) by the [`xkb-data` package](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=xkb-data).

1. Create `symbols/custom`

   ```
   // rotate the caps lock, left control, and escape keys so left control is on
   // the caps lock key
   partial modifier_keys
   xkb_symbols "rotatectrlcapsescape" {
       replace key <CAPS>      {  [ Control_L ] };
       replace key <LCTL>      {  [ Escape    ] };
       replace key <ESC>       {  [ Caps_Lock ] };
   };
   ```
2. Modify `rules/xorg`: look for the section `! option = symbols` and add

   ```
   custom:rotatectrlcapsescape = +custom(rotatectrlcapsescape)
   ```
3. (Optional) Update `rules/xorg.lst` and `rules/xorg.xml` (exercise left to reader).

Now the `custom:rotatectrlcapsescape` custom XKBOptions is available for use. As per Debian instructions, this is configured by default in `/etc/default/keyboard`, with a simple `XKBOPTIONS="custom:rotatectrlcapsescape"`.

Ubuntu/Gnome seems to use `rules/evdev*` instead of `rules/xorg*`.

### Downsides

- Modifying repository package files under `/usr/` is rarely a good idea. The modified files will probably be clobbered the next time the owning package (`xkb-data`) updates.

Answer (score 0):

What is in common between keyboard input in the console and XWindow is that in both cases, a USB keyboard driver in the kernel talks to the USB keyboard and produces scan codes. A change in that component of the system will affect all keyboard input.

See the static table `usb_kbd_keycode`, and related code, in the `drivers/hid/usbhid/usbkbd.c` source file in the kernel tree.